# Vanilla Javascript AddEventListener to horizontal resize (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I monitor if the viewport is resized in the horizontal direction?

I wish one of these existed ([but it doesn't](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)):

```
window.addEventListener( 'resizeX', this.fooBar );
window.addEventListener( 'resizeHorizontal', this.fooBar );
```

---

I currently use this: `window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.fooBar );` to monitor if the viewport-size changes. But on mobile device it's going craaaazy, due to the auto-hiding/showing of the navigation bar. 
So it would be better to only monitor *horizontal* resize.

Ideally, I'm looking for something that I can chuck in a mixin and add to all my Vue components. So it would be ideal if I didn't have to 'store the old/current' `viewportWidth` in a variable and overwrite it upon every resize. But that's *ideally*...

Here's what I tried:

```
...
data: function() {
  viewportWidth: 0,
  oldViewportWidth: 0,
  viewportWidthChanged: false
},
methods: {
  uponResize: function(){
    this.viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0, document.body.clientWidth);

    if( this.viewportWidth !== this.oldViewportWidth ){
      this.oldViewportWidth = this.viewportWidth;
      this.viewportWidthChanged = true;
    } else {
      this.viewportWidthChanged = false;
    }
  }
},
created() {
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.uponResize );
},
destroyed() {
window.removeEventListener( 'resize', this.uponResize );
}
...
```

**Remember**, that this is in a mixin. So that function runs upon every resize, *in every component*.

But `viewportWidthChanged' returns true, even if I only resize the browser in vertical direction.

Can anyone see why that is?

Comment: `document.body.clientWidth` will be bigger then the viewport's width if the `<body>` has horizontal scrolling.

Comment: If you have to use jQuery, just use jQuery. You can implement your own crazy custom bare-bones optimization once it works.